# "May" versus "might"

Tags: spoken-english, reported-speech, direct-speech

Direct speech: "You may borrow my car for a day."

I would like to convert this to indirect speech. Which option is more appropriate?

> A) He permitted to borrow his car for a day.

or

> B) He told her that she might borrow his car for a day.**

[I think the answer is B but it may also mean to give permission.]

Comment: This is not in common usage--I can't think of an example when I would use might or may this way.  Use "He told her that she could borrow his car" instead.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to ask the meaning of _may_ in this context or do you want to know what's the indirect form of your sentence? If it's the latter, B is the proper answer but I think @farnsy is right. It's not a common usage.

Comment: I want to ask which option is most appropriate , A or B.

Comment: "He permitted her to borrow his car" is fine.

Comment: I realized reading over this again, that, in fact,  **"may** has two uses in English. I have tried to sort them out in my answer and explain them. It took rereading the question several times for me to figure out why I was uncomfortable with might. I had sort of forgotten all this from my English teaching days...

Answer (score 1):

I think either option is correct if you change a couple of words. These are all acceptable sentences:

> He allowed her to borrow his car for a day. **[GOOD]**
>
> He let her borrow his car for a day. **[GOOD]**
>
> He permitted her to borrow his car for a day. **[OK, but not as common as above]**
>
> He told her she ***may*** borrow his car for a day. **[GOOD]**
>
> He told her she ***could*** borrow his car for a day. **[OK. This is so common in everyday speech that people will know what you mean, but avoid this in formal writing.]**

Option B as you wrote it above (**she *might* borrow**) does not express granting of permission as you intended.

Comment: Well, if you add "her" to it, it is grammatical, correct?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker. I think your examples are very good and helpful to people like me. Thank you for that. But, isn't ***may*** in the fourth example sentence wrong? I have been taught that when the tense is past, then **may** has to be converted into **might**, except when **may** is used to describe a possibility of an event that happened in the past.

Comment: @Lambie In the first sentence I say "if you change a couple of words," so I don't think what I said is misleading. 2 upvoters can't be wrong!

Comment: @SmartHumanism I think you might be right about "might." What flavor of English do you speak? In the US, it would be uncommon or even confusing to say *He told her she might borrow his car for a day.* This implies that she may or may not wish to borrow the car, and that he is somehow informing her of her own wishes: *He told her she might (want to) borrow the car.*

Comment: Thank you, for the reply. I think you're right. And I am not a native English speaking student who is learning English. The information I stated in the above comment could be totally wrong. I am sorry.

Comment: No, no, I think you're right, actually -- for Indian English or British English. I'm not really sure. I'm just saying it's not very common in the U.S.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two uses of **may** in English**

1) - To **ask permissio**n as in "May I borrow you car?"

Answer: Yes, you may; No, you may not.

AND

2) - **May** is a modal verb used to state something that is not 100% certain: [He said:] "You may borrow  his car tonight."

The reported speech for 1) would then be:

**He said she could borrow his car**. Or:

**He said she could not borrow his car**. [AKA **He gave her permission to borrow his car**.] This could even be: He allowed her to borrow his car. BUT: **it cannot be might**.

The reported speech for 2) in the present tense would then be:

He said she **may borrow** his car tonight.

Past Tense: He said she **might borrow** his car tonight.

In 2), **may** is used to express uncertainty about whether she will or will not borrow his car. In 1) one person is being asked permission by another to borrow something.